# Windows 10 UWP: How to display hardware status to user

Tags: windows-os, tablet

I'm currently writing a Surface 3 application for Windows 10 UWP. I've scoured the given design documentation but see no guidance provided for something of this nature.

My application communicates behind the scenes with a piece of hardware that the user leaves the software to interact with in various ways depending on the status of the hardware. There is a page in my application that is dedicated to this interaction. When a user interacts with the hardware it is blocking the UI and they are not intended to be able to use any other functionality of the software.

In previous versions of the software for Windows 8/8.1 I used windows ribbons but that doesn't seem to be an available pattern as of Windows 10. I'd be happy to answer any questions if I need to provide more information. Any suggestions are welcome as always!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Transient status

If you're looking for transient notification on hardware status changes, [UWP provides toast notifications](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh465391.aspx).

### Persistent status

If you need persistent status information, it's up to your needs. I designed a system with the requirement you describe and we ended up (still in MVP stage) with the status persistently displayed in the title bar. It's not specifically a UWP pattern, but this use case is highly specific. Make it fit the platform and users won't complain.

Comment: The toast notifications are interesting! I think I will do as you did and work something of my own within the app.